# Printing values from hash returns nil in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code:

```
person1 = { :first => "bob", :last => "perry"}
person2 = { :first => "fred", :last => "perry"}
person3 = {:first => "jane", :last =>"perry"}
family = {:dad => person1, :son => person2, :mum => person3}

puts (family[:dad][:last],family[:dad][:first])
```

It prints out:

```
perry
bob
nil
```

Why does it also output nil?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're in `irb`, which prints out the return value of the last method run, and `puts` returns nil.

<sup>*(Or in `rails c`.)*</sup>